# Another How to align faces of 2 objects question

Tags: objects

I am struggling with aligning face of one object to face of another object, my goal is to align obj1 "foot" face to obj2 face along with entire obj1 mesh if that makes sense. And make it so the obj1 rests on obj2 with its "foot" face. I know that my explaining skills are awful, but thats the best i can do. I'll attach images of what i mean down below. All help is welcome. Thanks
[image]

This is what I always end up with no matter of selected options, I tried moving the origin point to the foot face, making empty object and parenting obj1 to the empty, snapping to face with every option avaiable, attach-allign addon. No matter what I did, it always ended up like this or worse.
[image]

Few things to note: obj2 face is not in line with x or y axis, the face is basically rotated diagonaly and also rotated on Z axis, it is part of bigger object, but that should not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply the rotation on your object with it aligned to where the Z-axis is facing up for how you want to it align, and the origin at the bottom, then you can just use Face Snap with Align Rotation and Project Individual Elements enabled.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm. I don't know how I missed this.